# Android HelloWorld response

Tags: java, android, responsibility

I know that the heading of this thread sound silly, but I can not repair my code.

```
package HelloAndroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;

public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView view = new TextView(this);
    view.setText("LOL View Working!");
    setContentView(view);
}
}
```

My problem is that I'm getting error in emulator: process not reponding or something similair. Why?! This application is so small so why it does not works?! Please help me.

**EDIT**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="HelloAndroid.Main"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HelloAndroidActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: the code seems fine to me, you might however want to replace the `android.widget.*` import with only the specific classes you need.

Comment: show the logcat details.

Comment: It would help if we knew the exact error.  Is everything correctly added to the manifest?

Comment: Yes, everithing is like in tutorial. Wait please, I'm starting emulator (on my old ham).

Comment: with this code, we cant help....so add the manifest and the Log to your question

Comment: Unfortunately, HelloAndroid has stopped. - What? Why? This is error what I'm gtting no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `AndroidManifest.xml`, replace:

```
package="HelloAndroid.Main"
```

with:

```
package="HelloAndroid"
```

or move your java source file, into `HelloAndroid.Main` package by replacing the first line with:

```
package HelloAndroid.Main;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you get that error because package is not the same

in manifest u have: `package="HelloAndroid.Main"`
while in class is just `package HelloAndroid;`

hop

Comment: ah u r welcome.. we r here to help each other and make community better place for learning, not to compete how is faster ;) 
Cheers 

**Welcome to android wonderland ;)**

Comment: ah u got me wrong.. :S
I said I am not here to compete, but to learn and help others to learn.. ;) Eng.Fouad was first and he deserved Accepted..

Answer (score 1):

The

> package 'AndroidManifest.xml' must have a minimum of 2 segments.

So your package name should also have two segments like this

> com.HelloAndroid

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.Id);
    TextView view = new TextView(this);
    view.setText("LOL View Working!");
```